# How to find the index of a list that contains an int in python

Tags: python, list

If I have this list of lists

```
myList = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

and I would like to set myVar equal to the index of the list that contains the number 5. In the end myVar would equal 1. How would I do that? I am new to python so a simple answer would be appreciated.

Comment: use `for-loop` to get sublist from `myList` and then check `if 5 in sublist:`

Comment: Or, to get all sublists containing `5` use a list comprehension `[i for i, a in enumerate(myList) if 5 in a]`

Comment: If you're looking for the first index only `next(i for i,l in enumerate(myList) if 5 in l)`

Answer (score 3):

```
myList = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
# loop if 5 in the sub_list, than give the index
myVar = [myList.index(ls) for ls in myList if 5 in ls]
print myVar 
# 1
```

Comment: I suspect it's more efficient to use `enumerate` than to index `myList`

Answer (score 1):

Use `for`-loop to get sublist from `myList` and then check `if 5 in sublist:`

This way you find first row with `5`

```
my_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
my_var = None

for number, row in enumerate(my_list):
    if 5 in row:
        my_var = number
        break # don't search in other rows

print(my_var)
```

if you need all rows with `5` then you list for results

```
my_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
my_var = [] # list for all results

for number, row in enumerate(my_list):
    if 5 in row:
        my_var.append( number )

print(my_var)
```

or in one line

```
my_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

my_var = [number for number, row in enumerate(my_list) if 5 in row]

print(my_var)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may create a custom function using `enumerate()` to get the index as:

```
def get_index(my_list, val):
    for i, item in enumerate(my_list):
        if val in item:
            return i
    else:
        raise ValueError('{} not found in {}'.format(val, my_list))
```

Sample run:

```
>>> myList = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

# Valid value
>>> get_index(myList, 5)
1

# Invalid value
>>> get_index(myList, 22)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in get_index
ValueError: 22 not found in [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```